# What is the MySQL Workbench version of DATEDIFF(YEAR,C.END_DT,GETDATE())?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I understand the syntax for the current date will change from GETDATE() to SYSDATE().
How do we write the difference between the date from c.end column and the current date in terms of years in MySQL?
Do we use TIMESTAMPDIFF() ?

Comment: You should have mentioned what `DATEDIFF(YEAR,C.END_DT,GETDATE())` is and does. I suppose it is an expression taken from SQL Server. It is important to know that SQL Server only looks at the year in this expression. E.g. `SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2019-12-31', '2020-01-01')` returns 1 (year) although it's just 1/365 of a year (1 day). This is essential to know in order to properly answer the question.

Comment: It's often useful to provide more context, as the answer may change shape slightly depending on exactly what result is required, and what indexes are available

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get current year from MySQL, you just have to extract it using `YEAR()` function like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW());
```

`NOW()` returns todays date + time in this format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' so with `YEAR()`, you're just taking the year value from `NOW()`. Apply the same thing to the date field in your table like `YEAR(C.END_DT)` and do a subtraction between those year values. A simple query like this should work:

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(C.END_DT) 
FROM mytable C;
```

But if you still want to use `DATEDIFF`, you can write something like this:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),C.END_DT)) FROM mytable C;
```

`DATEDIFF` here return the differences in total days and using [FROM_DAYS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-days), it will return the total year, month and day from the specific date in the comparison.

Refer to this [updated fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/46NBiUi9fbYvLbPigPH8Nd/4)